# Child Cobobox Return Null if DataValue Combobox NotExist in Child table ( LINQ )

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, join, combobox

**information**

i have 3 table

`tblCountry`

[image]

`tblStateName`

[image]

`tblState`

[image]

`tblState` Child of `tblStateName` (`StateName_ID`) ( For Better Handle )

`tblState` Child of `tblCountry` (`Country_ID`) ( Cascade all Know This )

i create 1 form with 2 combobox

[image]

i use this code for load 2 combobox `DataValue`

```
    private void Form01_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load CountryComboBox Source from Table01
        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            // At first assign properties DisplayMember and ValueMember.
            cmbCountry.DisplayMember = "Country";
            cmbCountry.ValueMember = "Country_ID";

            // And then assign DataSource property of the CountryComboBox .
            cmbCountry.DataSource = db.CountryRepository.Get();
        }
    }

    //Load StateComboBox From Table02
    private void cmbCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValue = cmbCountry.SelectedValue.ToString();

        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
            {
                // At first assign properties DisplayMember and ValueMember.
                cmbState.DisplayMember = "StateName";
                cmbState.ValueMember = "State_ID";
                // And then assign DataSource property of the cmbState.
                var result = (from state in db.StateRepository.GetNameIDByFilter(selectedValue)
                                              join stateName in db.StateNameRepository.Get() on state.StateName_ID equals stateName.Statename_ID

                                              select new
                                              {
                                                  State_ID = state.State_ID,
                                                  StateName = stateName.StateName
                                              }).ToList();

                cmbState.DataSource = result;
            }
```

after load form i see this result

[image]

if i Select `Country01`, i see 4 Result in `cmbState` ( Its Well and Work Fine )

[image]

**MyProblem**

but if i Select 'Country02' ( this `Value` not child in tblState ) but i see First `Value` From tblState like this

[image]

**What I need ?**

how i can select Country02 and See Null in cmbState ?
or better ( Return Null If Country_ID not Exist in State table ) and cmbState is Null

( SRY For My bad English )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear `cmbState` after reloding data, if the `result` is *null or empty*, like the following code :

```
if(result == null || result.Count == 0)
{
 cmbState.DataSource = null;
 cmbState.DataBindings.Clear();
}else
{
 cmbState.DataSource = result;
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.